# Paste event anomaly with jQuery in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opera, paste

I am trying out this code. What it does is that when somebody right clicks on the first text box, shift the focus to the second, so that if he selects the `Paste` option from the context menu, the text is pasted in the second box. A `paste` event has been attached to the 2nd box to alert **Foo**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.foo').contextmenu(function() {
      $('.boo').select();
      return true;
  });
$(".boo").bind("paste",function() { alert("Foo"); });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = 'text' class = 'foo' />
<input type = 'text' class = 'boo' />
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine in all browsers except Opera. When  you right click and paste some text in the first box, the alert is popped for all these browsers. In Opera, if you paste some text directly in the 2nd box, the alert pops up all right. But if you do it via the first box, i.e shifting the focus to the 2nd while right-clicking on the first, so that the clipboard text gets pasted in the 2nd, it doesn't pop the alert, even though you can clearly see that the 2nd box has got the focus, and the text gets pasted there just fine. Can anyone tell me what is the problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: paste evemt is not supported by Opera browser. For Opera you can probably use DOM mutation event, e.g. DOMAttrModified event.

Comment: But if `paste` event is not supported, how come the alert is popped when you just focus on the 2nd box and paste text into it directly, either through `CTRL-C CTRL-V` or selecting `Paste` from context menu after right click?

Comment: Ok, I'm not jquery user, but I can imagine that there is some workaround/fix for paste event in jquery like in other frameworks. Try to investigate how it is solved in jquery's internals.

Comment: That is the problem. The `paste` event is a `paste` event, why does it matter that the focus is redirected from another text box? The event occurs only after the focus has been shifted. So in both cases, the event happens only when the 2nd box has got the focus.

Comment: @dherbolt: The `paste` event *is* implemented in current Opera versions - since [Presto 2.10](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.10/#m210-294)

Comment: You could implement the paste event yourself by rendering which key user presses (ctrl + v) for Opera only.

Comment: I didn't quite get that. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RKU92/), Opera fires the `paste` event on the element that was right-clicked on (while inserting the text where the focus was moved to). However, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RKU92/1/), the `input` event fires on the element where you had expected it.

> Can anyone tell me what is the problem, and how to fix it?

You are moving the selection/focus during the paste action (two clicks), which confuses both user and browser :-). I'm not sure how to fix this anomaly, but you certainly don't want move pastes to another input only if they were done via the contextmenu anyway.

Comment: What I am doing is to prevent the user inputting any data other than numers. The `CTRL-V` is taken care of, the context menu part is left. After shifting the focus, I am setting a quick timer to find whether the pasted text is a number chunk, if so, shift the focus back to the first box and paste it there. This works fine with Firefox, Safari, Chrome and even IE, how do I make it work for Opera?

Comment: Uh, I'd suggest not to use a second hidden input at all but just remove invalid text from the input when pasted there. However, as mentioned, you can listen for the `input` event on the second element to recognice pastes in Opera.

Comment: Hey dude, I am back again! This time with another problem! When I try it out in Opera 9, 10 and 11, what happens is this: On right clicking, the focus gets shifted to the 2nd box, the menu pops up near the first box. But when I do the paste, the text gets pasted in the first box and the focus again shifts back to the 2nd box! Any solution for this weird behavior?